how to make bluetooth connection for all fragments?
  override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        initBtAdapter()
        val pref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
            BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val mac = pref?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, "")
        bluetoothController = BluetoothController(btAdapter)
        try {

            if (item.itemId == R.id.id_color) {
                /*
                activity.let {
                    val intent = Intent(it, ColorGlow::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                 */
                binding.apply {

                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.ColorGlow)
                    }

                //view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.ColorGlow)

               // val i: Intent = Intent(requireContext(), ColorGlow::class.java)
               // startActivity(i)
            }  else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_distance) {
                binding.apply {

                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.GlimpsFragment)
                }
            }
            else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_bt_connect) { // Подключение к ESP32.
                bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this@MainFragment)
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Подключение к маяку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else if (item.itemId == R.id.onOff) {
                if (onOff == false) {
                    onOff = true
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Маяк включен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //btConnection.sendMessage("");
                } else {
                    onOff = false
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Маяк выключен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //btConnection.sendMessage("");
                }
            }   else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_search) {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.listFragment)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Сбой подключения$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

  package com.example.bluetoothmoduletest


import BluetoothController
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.bluetoothmoduletest.databinding.ColorGlowBinding
import com.example.bt_def.BluetoothConstants


class ColorGlow : Fragment(), BluetoothController.Listener {
    private lateinit var bluetoothController: BluetoothController
    private lateinit var btAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ColorGlowBinding



    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = ColorGlowBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    /*
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> finish()
        }
        return true
    }
*/

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initBtAdapter()
        bluetoothController = BluetoothController(btAdapter)
        val pref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
            BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        val mac = pref?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, "")
        bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this@ColorGlow)
        try {
            binding.apply {
                redButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("R") //RED
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали красный цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    }
                yellowButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("Y") //YELLOW
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали желтый цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()

                }
                greenButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("G") //GREEN
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали зеленый цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                }
                whiteButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("W") //WHITE
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали белый цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                }
                onOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                    if(isChecked) {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("L")
                        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Свет выключен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Сбой подключения$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }



    }
    private fun initBtAdapter(){
        val bManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        btAdapter = bManager.adapter
    }

I can't transfer the address and bluetooth connection to colorglow. help me transfer the Bluetooth connection without interrupting it when switching to another fragment!!!
I can't figure out how to make a connection to many fragments when switching to another fragment, the Bluetooth connection remains on the old fragment
